# Is there any tool like blob storage use for config local install file

Tags: windows-installer, blob

As we know, we can use blob storage in Azure to do some config for customer domain things. Is there any tool like that can do the same things locally, such as config for msi file.

Comment: You should explain what is a "config for msi file" and how it will be used. MSI files don't have config files, and it's not clear if the MSI install needs to access the data or some other program.

Comment: thanks for your reply. "config for msi file" means when we install the app could we have some way to config web.config it produced automatically, to apply customer's domain things.

Comment: the msi will generate web.config in its process, we need config web.config according to different customer setting, so this part in the config file cannot pre-define and build in the msi, I hope there are some way like blob storage, could add these customize accordingly. eg. for     <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>   <add name="some-option" value="${customize}">   </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol> I hope here could config ${costomize} accordingly.